# Make a program crash in exception handler (java)

Tags: android, exception, crash, libgdx, desktop

I am making a LibGDX game that works on android and desktop computers. Whenever there is an error, I catch it with a `try/catch`. Here is what I do:

```
try{
//Run code
}catch(Exception e){
    if(Game.isRunningOnAndroid())
        //Make application crash with error so Google can catch it and send it to my developer console
    else
        //Open error screen where desktop users can copy/paste the stack trace and send it to me
}
```

As you can see from the code above, what I would like to do is if the game has an error, I want to make the program crash like it normally would if I didn't catch the exception so that the error can be reported to my developer console on android. How do I do this? Is there a way to emulate the error to crash the program again? Thanks!

P.S. I already have the desktop error screen coded so I don't need answer relating to that. I just need a way to purposefully crash the program when it is run on android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-throw the original exception as follows:

```
try{
//Run code
}catch(Exception e){
    if(Game.isRunningOnAndroid())
        throw e
    else
        //Open error screen where desktop users can copy/paste the stack trace and send it to me
}
```